# How to show-hide the button based on if the closest radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, show-hide

Suppose,I have two quiz questions.Each question have radio buttons for selecting the answer and a clear answer button to clear the answer.
The clear button hide/show  only when the answer is selected/deselected in its respective question block.

How do I find if the radio button selected/deselected is of its nearest question block and show/hide clear button accordingly ?

[image: Here,is the screenshot of the scenario I am talking about.]

And,Here is the JS code I am currently using

```
jQuery(function($) {

if ($("input[type]").is(":radio")) {
    $(".answer").append("<button type='button' name='clear' >Clear</button>");
}

if ($("input[type=radio]:checked").length > 0) {
    $('button[name=clear]').show();
}
else{
    $('button[name=clear]').hide();
    }


$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function() {
    $nearest=  $(this).closest('.answer').find('button[name=clear]');
    $nearest.show();
});

$('button[name=clear]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.answer').find(':radio').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).hide();
});

if ($('.content').parent().hasClass("deferredfeedback")) {
    if ($('.answer .r0 input').prop('disabled')) {
        $("button[name=clear]").remove();
    }
} else {
    if (!($('div.im-controls').length)) {
        $("button[name=clear]").remove();
    }
}

});
```

somewhere I am missing out something which I am not able to find out,can someone guide me on this ?

Comment: Can you share your html? Maybe you can do it using CSS only.

Comment: you can do this using different ideas, 1) You can have each question + button in a div. So while clicking the button you can get the parent div and deselect all the radio buttons inside that 2) Give a tricky id names to radio buttons and clear button, so while getting the clear button id you could find the radio button related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the clear button there and hide it

CSS

```
.clearButton { display:none}
```

jQuery - assuming container per answer has class "answer" and
clear button has class "clearButton ":

```
$(function() {
  $(".answer").on("click","input[type=radio]",function() {
    $(this).closest(".answer").find(".clearButton").show();
  });
});
```

or if siblings:

```
$(function() {
  $(".answer").on("click","input[type=radio]",function() {
    $(this).siblings(".clearButton").show();
  });
});
```

For the clear you can use

```
  $(".answer").on("click",".clearButton",function() {
    $(this).siblings("input[type=radio]").prop("checked",false);
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

To show the clear button onload if some radios are already checked:

```
$("[type=radio]:checked").trigger("click")
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".answer").on("click", "input[type=radio]", function() {
    $(this).closest(".answer").find(".clearButton").show();
  });


  $(".answer").on("click", ".clearButton", function() {
    $(this).siblings("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).hide();
  });


  $("[type=radio]:checked").trigger("click")

});
```

```css
.clearButton {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answer">
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1">Answer 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="2">Answer 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="3">Answer 3</label>
  <button type="button" class="clearButton">Clear</button> 
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="answer">
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="1">Answer 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="2" checked>Answer 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="3">Answer 3</label>
  <button type="button" class="clearButton">Clear</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your suggestions,but I want is to retain the clear button till it is pressed,suppose,I have multiple pages with each having 2 questions on it.In the current case,if i move to second page,the clear button is no longer visible when I come back on the first page.

Comment: Please see update. Last statement goes into the $function after the event handlers

Comment: Sorry,but it doesn't trigger the click

Comment: Well,I got the solution.Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: @AmrataRamchandani - please see my example - it works. You need to insert it correctly in your code. I had to GUESS your HTML

Comment: Thanks again,for your efforts put in @mplungan ,On click of the clear button doesn't clear off the the selected radio button and morevover when I come back to the first page from 2nd page,It shows the clear button for both the questions on the page even if only one of the 2 questions have its answer selected. And I have already got my solution,so no worries,cheers :)

Comment: Ok I’ll take a look when SO is back up where I live

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

Js Code here

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("button").hide();
  $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(e){
        $(this).closest('.answers').find("button").show();
  });
  $("body").on("change","input[type='radio']" ,function(){
    $(this).closest('.answers').find("button").show();
  });

  $("body").on("click","button" ,function(){
    $(this).closest('.answers').find("input[type='radio']:checked").prop("checked",false);
    $(this).hide();
  });
})
```

[click here to show jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhaval_123/dy1vqqx3/6/)

Comment: Not recommended to remove and add DOM elements when they can be hidden and shown

Comment: Now it looks like mine

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your suggestions,but I want is to retain the clear button till it is pressed,suppose,I have multiple pages with each having 2 questions on it.In the current case,if i move to second page,the clear button is no longer visible when I come back on the first page.

Comment: Hi, Please check updated code for your solution  - - - **Amrata**